# audioplayerdidfinishplaying problem! iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, avfoundation

After a sound has finished, another sound could play...but in this code sounds are mixing...How can I fix it?

```
-(IBAction) ... {
   for ( ...) {
     if (compare(Output, N1)) {
       songPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"wav"];
     }
     if (compare(Output, N2)) {
       songPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b" ofType:@"wav"];
     }
     audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: songPath] error:NULL];
                [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
                [audioPlayer play];
   }
}


-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player successfully: (BOOL) flag {
  NSLog(@"Song FINISHED!!!!!!");
  [player release];
}
```

Comment: You've put `[audioPlayer play]` in a `for` loop. Obviously, if loop has more than 1 iteration than you'll have several audio players playing together.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user taps the button the audio player plays but it seems like if the audio is not finished and user taps it again the another object of audio player is created with the another reference to the audio file. This makes two or evenmore audio to play at the same time. Well, the solution is simple. Just check to see every time when the button is tapped, if the player is already playing, if so stop the player and release and create a new instance with new file url reference .To do this you should synthesize audioPlayer and use it as,

```
-(IBAction) ... {
   for ( ...) {
   if (compare(Output, N1)) {
     songPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"wav"];
   }
   if (compare(Output, N2)) {
     songPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b" ofType:@"wav"];
   }
   if(self.audioPlayer){
     self.audioPlayer.delegate=nil;
     self.audioPlayer=nil;
    }
   self.audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                           [NSURL fileURLWithPath: songPath] error:NULL];
   [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
   [self.audioPlayer play];
  }
 }


-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player successfully: (BOOL) flag {
     NSLog(@"Song FINISHED!!!!!!");
     [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:nil];   
     self.audioPlayer=nil; 
  }
```

Comment: Does it cause a problem setting self.audioPlayer=nil
and then doing [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:nil]; ?

Comment: Yes it does, the code above is wrong it audioPlayer should be set to nil after the delegate is set to nil. Since the delegate is weak property of the audio player itself, is is not retained by the audioplayer, it may not crash but it is not a correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't really understandable, but I think I get what your goal is.

To implement it, lets say, you have an `NSArray *itemsToPlay`.
In the very beginning (i.e. when user taps your button) it's filled with all your sounds.

After user taps the button, `IBAction` is called. There you pick the first sound from `itemsToPlay` (and remove it from this container) and tell the `audioPlayer` to play.

After player is finished playing, `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` is called. There you once again pick the first item from `itemsToPlay` and re-init your `audioPlayer` with it. Again, say `audioPlayer` to play.

This cycle will end when `itemsToPlay` is empty.